# How to bypass special characters in a dynamic anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a dynamic anchor tag by adding some values. But in case of special characters the code is breaking:

`'<a href="#" onclick="openCI(\''+var1+'\',\''+ var2 +'\',\''+ var3 +'\',\''+ var4 +'\')">' + LINK_URL + '</a>'`

In above case, when the LINK_URL value contains special characters, the code breaks. Is there any way to fix this?

I tried the following value in LINK_URL: !@#$%^&*()-=+_';":.,<>/?

If I use `escape()` function in javascript, the value displayed does not match the actual value: %21@%23%24%25%5E%26*%28%29-%3D+_%27%3B%3A.%2C%3C%3E/%3F

How to parse this value and display it as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to worry about `<>&"` characters. You can replace these characters for the html equivalent.

```
LINK_URL.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
```

Or you can do it in a more elegant way:

```
String.prototype.htmlEscape = function() {
   return this.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
}

LINK_URL.htmlEscape();
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/x3ypLmzo/1/)

Comment: i see you have escaped double quotes using "\" or escape character

Comment: It's because I'm writing a literal string (eg. "any text"). You don't have to do it if you are using variables (eg.: LINK_URL)

Answer (score 0):

Just push your `href` elements or variables as a string in array like this

```
var arr=[];

arr.push('"');
arr.push("@");
arr.push("$");
arr.push("%");
arr.push('"');
console.log(arr.join(""));
```

then attach array `arr` in your a tag

for sample here http://jsfiddle.net/Lz760k2j/1/